# Can i get tesseract accuracy?

Tags: python-2.7, tesseract

I'm trying to use tesseract to recognize numbers in images with some noises. Is it possible to get tesseract accuracy in specified output through python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tesseract confidence value. `TesserractExtractResult()` returns the confidence numbers for all characters returned. A high number means low confidence.
check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098845/character-wise-confidence-values-using-tesseract-3-01) and [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/ztvz7qKCZhg)